# How do I use helpers with Dust.js on a local environment?

Tags: javascript, helper, dust.js

I'm programming using dust-full.js from the linkedIn fork (2.5.1). I'm trying to use helpers for conditionals, but I can't seem to get it to work. Right now, I'm using my local machine (I have no intention at the moment to include a server backend, but it may be where this project goes). I currently test my code on my Dropbox public folder. All non-helper code has worked.

The code in question:

```
    {?quote temp="4"}
        Once you have chosen the best answer{@if cond="{temp} > 1"}s{/if}, please select the "Submit" button.
    {:else}
        Choose the best answer{@if cond="{temp} > 1"}s{/if}, then select the "Submit" button.
    {/quote}
```

I have previously added the dust-full.js distribution and helpers like so:

```
<script src="script/dust-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/dust-helpers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I saw in other threads and on the dust.js [tutorial](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#Helpers) that one needed to "require" the helpers. Using code like this:

```
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');
dust.helper = require('dustjs-helpers');
```

However, when I include this, I get the console error: "ReferenceError: require is not defined." I assume that this is because "require" is usually used/included in node.js, but I honestly don't know. I would prefer not to include node.js, as I don't know it and I'm not interested in learning additional libraries. However, I do not know how to evaluate helpers.

I have four questions:

1. Are there any obvious bugs in the code I've provided?
2. Are dust.js helpers only available using when using server-side scripting?
3. (Assuming the answer to 2 is "No") Can helpers be used only with dust-full.js and dust-helpers.js?
4. (Assuming the answer to 3 is "No") How does one use helpers only using client-side scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `require` to load the helpers is for a server environment like Node. You should be able to do exactly what you've done to load the helpers-- just include them after the main dust script and they'll be automatically added to the `dust` object.

What you've done looks correct, so is it possible that you've used the wrong path to your dust-helpers Javascript file?

Here is a snippet showing the `{@gt}` helper working. (The `{@if}` helper is deprecated, so you'll get warnings in the console when you use it-- but `{@gt}` does exactly what you want.)

```html
<div id="output"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-linkedin/2.5.1/dust-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dustjs-helpers/1.5.0/dust-helpers.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var tmpl = dust.compile('Hello World! Choose the best answer{@gt key=temp value=1}s{/gt}', "test"),
      context = { "temp": 4 };
  dust.loadSource(tmpl);
  dust.render("test", context, function(err, out) {
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = out;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Arg, missed my chance to edit. Meant to say more. 
I think the issue I had was with my directories, so I'll clean that up. I tried to run it with my code with directories you sent, but I can't get the parameter "temp" to work. Any suggestions on how correct that? Do you have an example of how to use that feature?

Comment: I was just mimicking your example. `temp` is just a variable in my context object.